# Understanding a step in Exercises on Euclid about the square of a side

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I've started working through the exercises in Casey's edition of Euclid as found [here.](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/21076/21076-pdf.pdf)

I'm stuck on a step that appears to relate to the Pythagorean Theorem, but I can't see why it's true. It's a bit hard to share the details except with images, and the construction steps of exercises 1-3 need to be completed before exercise 4 can be done. My question is, in solution 4, why does GC² = 4AG²?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is it given that $A$ and $B$ are the centres of the respective circles, so that $AB$ is the common radius? It is unclear what information is given - and even whether the two circles are given to be the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$AC$ is a radius of the circle and $GC$ is a diameter of the same.
$$\frac{GC}{AC}=2\\[4ex]\frac{GC^2}{AC^2}=4\\[4ex]GC^2=4AC^2$$